# Using $index in ngRepeat declaration in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have data that has unique identifiers in the json property and I want to access this in the ng-repeat directive.

This fails:

```
<tr ng-repeat="shape in 'shapes.id_'+$index+'.objects')"></tr>
```

Any ideas how I can do this? I thought of maybe using a function call

```
<tr ng-repeat="shape in shapes($index))"></tr>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat="shape in shapes['id_'+$index].objects')"`

Comment: Where is `$index` coming from? Would it make more sense to compute a valid array with relevant items in controller and store it in scope instead?

Comment: Could you give us a example of the 'shapes' json object ?

Comment: json object structure would be helpful.

Comment: CodeHater's answer works, if I could hug him through this monitor I would!